# Como comunicar y renderizar datos de manera cruzada entre componentes de VUE

Tags: vue.js

gracias por tomarse un minuto y leer mi problema.

Tengo el siguiente caso. Estoy consumiendo una API de productos que devuelve `nombre`, `precio` y `cantidad`.

Para tal caso me sirvo de 3 componentes:

ComponenteA ,  ComponenteB y ComponenteC.

**En el componenteA:**

- Tengo un input que ejecuta un onchange luego de escribir lo que voy a buscar,
- El onchange ejecuta una funcion que recibe por parametro el valor del input y realiza la consulta a la API con AXIOS.
- El AXIOS retorna una respuesta y la guarda en una variable de tipo Array que paso por props al `componenteB`
- El componenteB hace un FOR del array recibido por el ComponenteA y renderiza unas tarjetas con la data.
- Las tarjetas se renderizan dentro del componenteA.

**Ahora el problema**: Quiero pasarle por props (o como sea) otro Array al componenteB pero desde el componenteC pero que las tarjetas se rendericen en el componenteA. tal cual como cuando busco desde el componenteA y se renderiza la data allí mismo.

Imagino que utilizarían VUEX. Pero me gustaría evitar hacerlo!

Los leeo, muchas gracias.

Comment: El propósito de vuex es evitar hacer esto que plantea. Vuex o pinia tendrá ese estado para todos sus componentes,  ¿Por qué complicarse?

Comment: Estimado, gracias por responder. Pues, tiene razón. Creo que no me quedará mas remedio que instalar VUEX. Solo que queria ahorrarme la libreria ya que es algo basico el proyecto. Supuse, que alguien podría tener una solucion con $emit y $once por ejemplo. Saludos